# Saving video output

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

i was trying to save a processed video in opencv-python working in Ubuntu 16.04. I am able to visualise the processed video. But, When i try to save the video, its giving me the following errors. Any possible suggestions?

```
from collections import deque
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils
import argparse
black_lower = (0,0,0)
black_upper = (100, 110, 138)
kernel_erode = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
kernel_dialate = np.array((2,2),np.uint8)
center = None
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=2048,help="max buffer   size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
pts = deque(maxlen = args["buffer"])
video = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/users/Desktop/opencv_files/fun_video.mp4')
while (video.isOpened()):
num, frame = video.read()
frame1 = imutils.resize(frame,width=600)
frame2 = frame1[210:500,11:455]
mask = cv2.inRange(frame2,black_lower,black_upper)
mask1 = cv2.erode(mask,kernel_erode, iterations=1)
mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask1,kernel_dialate,iterations=6)
contours=cv2.findContours(mask2.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
if len(contours) > 0:
    c = max(contours,key = cv2.contourArea)
    ((x,y),radius)=cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c) #(x,y) are the coordinates by which the ants are moving
    print (x,y)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
    if radius > 6:
        cv2.circle(frame2,(int(x),int(y)),int(radius),(0,0,255),1)
        cv2.circle(frame2,center,5,(0,0,255),1)
pts.append(center)
for i in xrange(1,len(pts)):
    if pts[i-1] is None or pts[i] is None:
        continue
    thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 0.50)
    cv2.line(frame2, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
cv2.imshow('frame2', frame2)
#cv2.imshow('mask', mask2)
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/users/Desktop/output7.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (160,160))
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('file.avi', -1, 20.0, (640, 480))
if cv2.waitKey(50) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/users/PycharmProjects/cv_test/rest.py", line 19, in <module>
frame1 = imutils.resize(frame,width=600)
File "/home/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imutils  /convenience.py", line 69, in resize
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: you should provide the code, not only the error message. are we supposed to guess how you save the images? the error suggests that you put something into imutils.resize that is not an image and has no shape.

Comment: @Piglet apologies, code is attached!

Comment: @Piglet i was able to solve it, the problem was because the codec was trying to write the video before reaching the final frame. So once i gave my "num" as False, it was working! So the errors are out